# MYSQL LEFT JOIN select enhance

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a select with left join just wondering if i am doing it correctly.

I am got two tables a job table and a job assign table, i would like to select job creator and also job who have been assigned as well. the following code i have used 1 for id.

```
    JOB Table
++++++++++
    id
    user_id (capture creator id)
    title

    JOB ASSIGN TABLE
++++++++++
    id
    job_id 
    user_id (capture assign id)
```

========

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.title
FROM
    job a
LFET JOIN job_assign b
ON
    a.id = b.job_id 
WHERE
(
    a.user_id = 1
        OR
    b.user_id =1
)
```

The above query works but its a bit slow, and when i check Explain

```
1
SIMPLE
b
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
358
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

is there anyway to enhance my query, would be a good lesson for me :)

Comment: "WHERE a = 1"? What does that mean?

Comment: @Strawberry sorry a.user_id my bad left it out

Comment: @Strawberry no, i want to select the a.user_id is the creator id, and b.user_id is when other people assign to the. There are situation the user is not the creator and assigned to

Comment: OK. It seems like there are some flaws in your query, but I'd really need to see proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) to help further.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry i confused you :( my explanation is not very well... Thanks anyhow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes will help (and the one suggested by @Volkan Ulukut will greatly speed up the join ), but as a single query the OR in the WHERE clause will make it difficult for MySQL to use an index.

It might be worth splitting it into 2 queries and unioning the results together:-

```
SELECT a.id, a.title
FROM job a
WHERE a.user_id = 1
UNION
SELECT a.id, a.title
FROM job_assign b
INNER JOIN job a
ON a.id = b.job_id 
WHERE b.user_id = 1
```

If you do this after adding the following indexes it should hopefully be quicker:-

```
CREATE INDEX job_user_id ON job (user_id);

CREATE INDEX job_assign_user_id ON job (user_id);
```

Done this way it can use an index on the job title to check the user id, and on the 2nd part of the query it can use an index on user id to get the rows from job_assign, and then the index on id (which I assume is a primary key) for table job to do the join.

Comment: Thanks kickstart, so UNION in this situation would be even faster than join? i will try it out thanks heaps up vote

Comment: It is a bit of a fiddle but yes it can help. The problem is that when you check the value of one field OR the value of another field in a single SELECT, MySQL can't use indexes on both of them.

Answer (score 1):

you could add an index to foreign key job_id

```
CREATE INDEX job_assign_jobid ON job_assign (job_id);
```

Comment: Thanks Volkan i will try that see if it helps up vote first :)